# Count instances of element in c# list

Tags: c#, list, linq

I'd like to know how to `Count` the instances of the *first element* in a list, then the *second* etc. and output these values.

```
var SPFK_List = new List<string>() {
  "one", "one", "one",
  "two", "two",
  "three", "three", "three"
};

Inputs.ones.Value = *(number of one's)*
Inputs.twos.Value = *(number of two's)*
```

Comment: Thanks for the responses! My final code included:

`Inputs.first.Value = List.Where(x => x.Equals(Distinct_List[2])).Count();`

Where the distinct list is a list of added distinct values from the first list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A possible solution:

```
Inputs.ones.Value = SPFK_List.Where(x => x.Equals("one")).Count();
```

Comment: You could replace Where with Count and remove the last Count to make if even simplier.

Comment: @MightyBadaboom: didn't think about it, feel free to edit if you have optimizations.

Answer (score 5):

Try `GroupBy` (*Linq*), e.g.:

```
using System.Linq;

...

var SPFK_List = new List<string>() {
  "one", "one", "one",
  "two", "two", 
  "three", "three", "three"
};

// {3, 2, 3}
int[] counts = SPFK_List
  .GroupBy(item => item)
  .Select(group => group.Count())
  .ToArray();
```

Or (add `Where` if you want to count only some items)

```
// {{"one", 3}, {"two", 2}, {"three", 3}}
Dictionary<string, int> counts = SPFK_List
 //.Where(item => item == "one" || item == "two") 
  .GroupBy(item => item)
  .ToDictionary(group => group.Key, group => group.Count());

Inputs.ones.Value = counts.TryGetValue("one", out int count) ? count : 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply use [`Count`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.count?view=netframework-4.8#System_Linq_Enumerable_Count__1_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0_System_Boolean__) method from `System.Linq` with overload accepting a `Func<TSource,bool>` predicate

```cs
var SPFK_List = new List<string>() {
    "one", "one", "one",
    "two", "two",
    "three", "three", "three"
};

Inputs.ones.Value = SPFK_List.Count(s => s.Equals("one", StringComparison.Ordinal));
Inputs.twos.Value = SPFK_List.Count(s => s.Equals("two", StringComparison.Ordinal));
```